# The following code for "prime sieve" is not working with Release mode ,,but works perfectly with Debug mode

Tags: debugging, release

The following code for "prime sieve" is not working with Release mode ,,but works perfectly with Debug mode.. I cannot figure out why ,, am using Microsoft Visual c++ 2010 express

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <time.h>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
void main(){

    clock_t start= clock();

    int n = 10000000;
    bool* primes= new bool[n];
    primes[0]=0;
    int g = (int)sqrt(n*1.0) +1;
    for (int i = 2 ;i <g ; i++){
        if(primes[i]){
            for (__int64 j = i*i ; j <n ; j+=i)
                primes[j]=0;
        }

    }
    printf("Time elapsed: %f\n", ((double)clock() - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    int* p = new int[n/2];
    int c = 0;
    for (int x = 0 ; x<n ; x++)
        if (primes[x]){
            p[c]=x;
            c++;
        }

    cout<<p[481516]<<endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: How is it "not working"? Not compiling? Throwing an exception? Wrong answers?

Comment: @hatchet in debug it gives
"Time elapsed: 0.513000
7076453"
in Release
"Time elapsed: 0.000000
0"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't initialized the rest of the values in your primes array before you start accessing them. Try adding

```
for (int i=1; i<n; i++)
    primes[i] = 1;
```

before your calculation of g.

Comment: thanks alot ^^ ,, worked perfectly , but is there a faster way to initialize it ,, i want to save everysingle second

Comment: I would recommend asking that as a separate question since it might be helpful to other people who may not come across it if we discuss it in comments.